# C# ASP.NET - Generar un archivo de excel de un objeto modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Hola amigo tengo una función que recibe un json con un modelo particular, necesito que toda la info que paso por este json, convertirla en un excel y guardarlo dentro de una carpeta en mi servidor, alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo???

este es mi modelo y la función donde lo recibo, al final solo quiero devolver un string que diga, excel generado o que devuelva el error en un string

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string SaveCreditQuotation(SolicitudCreditoCalculadora creditQuo){


        var response = "";
        var message = creditQuo.fullmsn.ToString();
        var mail_user = creditQuo.mail_user.ToString();

        response = "yeah";
        // response = "nos comunicaremos contigo vía el mail:" + mail_user + " , si surge algún desperfecto comunicate con nostros";



        return response ; 
    }
```

Esta es mi clase

```
 public class Payment
    {
        public string IndicePago { get; set; }
        public string Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Cantidad { get; set; }
    }

public class SolicitudCreditoCalculadora
{


    public string mail_user { get; set; }
    public string fullmsn { get; set; }
    public List<Payment> payments { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera muy sucia de hacerlo es generando un `datatable` y luego crear un `stringbuilder` de la tabla para finalmente crear el archivo.
Aqui un ejemplo:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//Se llama a la funcion que convierte el DT en un SB para convertirlo a excel
sb = DataTableToSb(dt);

//Se crea el nombre del archivo EJ: #OM84674_FRE-40_1.xls
string filename = "Nombre"+ id + ".xls";

HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

return File(buffer, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Funcion que convierte la datatable

```
public StringBuilder DataTableToSb(DataTable dt) 
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<table>");
            //write column headings
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<td><b><font face=Arial size=2>" + dc.ColumnName + "</font></b></td>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");

            //write table data
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (System.Data.DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td><font face=Arial size=" + "14px" + ">" + dr[dc].ToString() + "</font></td>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }
            sb.Append("</table>");

            return sb;

        }
```

Y la otra es usar una libreria gratuita del nuget llamada Epplus

https://riptutorial.com/epplus

Comment: habrá una manera más limpia ? no hay algo así como pasar el puro modelo y pum!!!! excel sheet?

Comment: hehehe no que yo conozca, pero si la encuentras, pues compartela :D Puede que haya alguna libreria por ahi que desconozco

Comment: oye solo una preguntota, ese buffer cómo lo guardo en una carpeta??